# Unable to install Tensorflow 2.0 with GPU support in Google colaborate

Tags: tensorflow, pip, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to predict stock prices with a Long short-term memory (LSTM) machine learning model but am unable to as I cannot install Tensorflow 2.0 with GPU support in google colaborate.

I've tried searching the index database for an index that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0, but was unable to.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is already pre-installed with latest stable version in Google Colab. You can just import the tensorflow using below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

To access the Tensorflow with GPU, you can change the Google Colab runtime to GPU

**Menu(top) - Runtime - Change runtime type - Hardware accelerator - GPU - Save**

[image]

Please use the code below to confirm if the GPU is enabled:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices()
```

You will not be able to downgrade the `Tensorflow version<2.8`(Tensorflow 2.0 require min python 3.7) as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) because Google colab has upgraded `Python 3.10.12` version.